# faceted browsing + chart plotting for structured data

Tags: visualization

I'm looking for a web open source solution for browsing a structured dataset, to be integrated in an existing web application

Given a structured dataset (a table with 50K rows), user would filter the data using facets and a chart would be displayed showing only the filtered data.

I'm thinking about something similar to Google Refine using only facets and the scatter plot facet. But I wonder if there is something more modular than Google Refine in order to be integrated easily into my web application. Do you know of any library or framework or lightweight solution?

Answer (score 0):

Google refine have a python library now http://pypi.python.org/pypi/refine-client might be worth to check it out.